# Where do I execute "rails generate scaffold" command in AptanaStudio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

There used to be a UI for scaffolding a model in my previous version of AptanaStudio.  Where did this functionality go?  Must I use the command line exclusively?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use the console provided in Aptana.
reference: http://beans.seartipy.com/category/ruby/
hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will try it out.  Until then, the CLI worked for me.